# windows 10 - make taskbar itself a different color from the taskbar buttons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I use the taskbar vertically down the screen with Ungrouped icons. In windows 7, the background color of the taskbar itself was different from the background color of the buttons on it, so it was possible to see the gaps between the groups. in windows 10, there is still a small gap between the groups but because there's no difference in background color, it's not really possible to detect it just from the spacing

Is there any way to achieve this in Windows 10? It seems a pointless removal of functionality and it's really hurting my productivity at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a problem just like this.  In Windows 10 the active buttons are highlighted by a small green strip at the bottom of the button, only about 3-10 pixels in width.  If your screen is not properly sized then this green strip is not visible on the monitor and you cannot see which buttons are active and which are not.

As yet, it is not possible to change the background color of the buttons in Windows 10.  This may change with new updates in the future.

Comment: yes I can see the small strip 2 pixels wide (though for me it's on the right and not green). the gap between the strips is 8 pixels for windows in the same group and 9 pixels for windows in a different group, but that difference is not enough for me to tell visually the groups :-(

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree that vertical task bar improves productivity. That is why I am putting together a project to re-thing the Win OS user interface, building on old validated ones: http://www.winglaze.com/

This will solve your problem ultimately!

Please, share, comment and support. Thanks!

Comment: I also prefer my taskbars vertically, which is already possible. I don't see the use of the favorite and undo buttons, and would hate to accidentally click the shutdown button right next to the start button. Shutting down is a much less common action than using the start menu, so its button should be less prominent. The small buttons make it hard to use on tablets and phones, which are more popular than desktops or even laptops now. I would unify the quicklaunch and shortcut areas, and neatly tuck them away in the start menu, like tiles.

Comment: @Marjan abandoned the project winglaze?